# Selected wrong travel document type during Wizzair online check-in by mistake. Is this a problem?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, online-resources, check-in, wizz-air

When checking in for my flight on the Wizzair website, I accidentally chose National ID instead of Passport as the document type. The date of issue, expiration date, and document number are otherwise correct.

According to the FAQ, mistakes during online check-in can be corrected by calling the Wizzair hotline. However, I have read that you are likely to spend ages on hold and since these calls are billed at something like 2 euros per minute, I would like to avoid this if possible.

Am I likely to experience any issues when dropping off my checked luggage or during boarding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I've flown with Wizz more times than I can count, and system bugs have caused this issue for me more than once. No one cares about it (and no one from Wizz is going to check your documents anyway)

So leave it be.

Comment: I accidentally registered with my first and last names in the wrong order, and I more than once accidentally used "Afghanistan" as the nationality or country of issue (as it's the first option in the list), but never had any questions raised on the airport

Comment: A quick follow-up: nothing happened in my case either.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that you are likely to spend ages on hold and since these
>   calls are billed at something like 2 euros per minute [...]

You'll be glad to hear that neither of these are necessarily true.

Firstly, I have called WizzAir thrice (twice in the past month) for customer service related enquiries and each time I was on hold in a queue for less than a minute and the agent dealt with my issue quickly and efficiently.

Secondly, since your enquiry is related to an existing booking, you don't have to call the premium rate enquiry number, but instead you can call the UK local rate number for existing bookings [(source)](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us#/) which is +44 330 977 0444. The other way to avoid calling a premium rate number is to call one of the international numbers from the link above and find an English-speaking operator. I haven't tried this myself, but the Malta enquiry number is +356 2778 1054 which is a domestic rate number and almost everyone in Malta speaks English. There are many ways to call international numbers cheaply these days - Skype for example charges 16 euro cents to call a domestic Maltese number. If that doesn't work, there are several other numbers at the link above which charge substantially less than 2 euros per minute.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same mistake once called them and they fixed it in 1 minute. No waiting no hassle. Fix it cause u dont know who will be at the check in station